# Why Application.Worksheetfunction.Countifs doesn`t return value?

Tags: vba, excel, variables, worksheet-function, sumifs

```
Dim SJtempARTIST, SJtempSTATION, SJtempADD, SJtempSPINS, targetCELL As Range
Dim stationARTIST, stationSTATION As String

Sheets("STATIONS").Select
For RARTSTAT = 2 To lrARTSTAT1

stationARTIST = Worksheets("STATIONS").Cells(1, cARTIST)
stationSTATION = Worksheets("STATIONS").Cells(RARTSTAT, 2)
Set SJtempARTIST = Worksheets("TEMPDB").Range("A1:A" & lrSJIMPORT2)
Set SJtempSTATION = Worksheets("TEMPDB").Range("C1:C" & lrSJIMPORT2)
Set SJtempADD = Worksheets("TEMPDB").Range("F1:F" & lrSJIMPORT2)
Set SJtempSPINS = Worksheets("TEMPDB").Range("E1:E" & lrSJIMPORT2)
Set targetCELL = Sheets("STATIONS").Cells(RARTSTAT, cARTIST)

checkRECORD = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(SJtempSTATION, _
stationSTATION, SJtempARTIST, stationARTIST)
checkADD = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(SJtempSTATION, _
stationSTATION, SJtempARTIST, stationARTIST, SJtempADD, 1)
checkSPINS = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SJtempSPINS, _
SJtempSTATION, stationSTATION, SJtempARTIST, stationARTIST)
checkX = InStr(1, LCase(targetCELL), "x")
checkADD = InStr(1, LCase(targetCELL), "add")
```

Hello guys. Well here is one part of code. Variable checkADD returns value 0 while clearly it shouldn`t, as rest of variables returning values properly. Anyway, here is more info:

checkRECORD finds and count properly 1 record. checkADD should too as it is using same method with one criteria and range more (in that F1:F column values can be either 0 either 1, and I want to count 1`s).

Ive tried with SUMIFS to, but still doesnt count anything. Ive checked ranges, and checked criteria`s and everything is fine! Ive tried without variables (with full ranges) but without luck.

So question is... why COUNTIFS doesnt work here?

Thnx in advance

Comment: One quick note: only `targetCELL` is being declared as a range in your code. The rest of the variables are being declared as variants. In order to get the correct data type it should be `Dim SJtempARTIST As Range, SJtempSTATION As Range, SJtempADD As Range, SJtempSPINS As Range, targetCELL As Range`. Likewise only `stationSTATION` is a string. `stationARTIST` is a variant. There probably isn't a tangible difference but sometimes for code readability more explicit declarations is preferable.

Comment: Does the desired formula work when you enter it into Excel as an actual formula?

Comment: @Soulfire, Thnx noticing that, I`ll correct it just in case. @Scott Holtzman, yes it works, it returns 1. Ive tried various ways of doing this in VBA with different methods but always returns 0. Ive checked how cell is formatted and everything, but it isnt that.

Comment: `checkADD = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(SJtempSTATION, stationSTATION, SJtempARTIST, stationARTIST, SJtempADD, ">0")` Ive tried this too but doesnt help (value in cell matching those criteria is 1)

Comment: `checkADD = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SJtempADD, SJtempSTATION, stationSTATION, SJtempARTIST, stationARTIST)` and Ive tried this too

Comment: and also full address instead of variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys for taking your time, mistake was mine ofc....

```
checkADD = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(SJtempSTATION, _
stationSTATION, SJtempARTIST, stationARTIST, SJtempADD, 1)
checkSPINS = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SJtempSPINS, _
SJtempSTATION, stationSTATION, SJtempARTIST, stationARTIST)
checkX = InStr(1, LCase(targetCELL), "x")
checkADD = InStr(1, LCase(targetCELL), "add")
```

I named checkADD variable two times. It is too late I guess, I should rest a bit...